# Make a dice value attach to dynamic javascript made html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So i'm doing a little dice game in javascript/jquery. I get some users (In this case players) from a `REST API` that i get with `AJAX` Like this:

```
var APICaller = (function () {
    let endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

    function api_call(method, url, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function get_users(callback) {
        let method = "GET";
        let url = endpoint + "users";
        let data = {};
        api_call(method, url, data, callback);
    }

    return {
        get_users: get_users, 
    };
})();
```

The person playing the game can choose a player from the user list and then press the play button.

When the play button is pressed the dice should roll 3 numbers for each player and display all the numbers at the side of each player. And then the dice value list should change after a time and only the total amount of the three dice values should be in that list, and also the user list should be in points order with the highest total points on the top.

This is the way I have tried to make these things happen:

```
var Game = (function (){

    //Function for when the dice rolls.
    function roll_dice(){
        var value1 = $(".val1");
        var value2 = $(".val2");
        var value3 = $(".val3");
        var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var v3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var dice_total = v1 + v2 + v3;
        value1.text = v1;
        value2.text = v2;
        value3.text = v3;
    }

    return{
        roll_dice: roll_dice
    };
})();

var EventHandlers = (function () {
    function init(){
        APICaller.get_users(on_get_users_success);

        function on_get_users_success(response) {
            //For each user in the API
            $.each(response, function (i, user) {
                $("#my-list").append('<li class="list-li"><a class="list-a">' + user.name + '</a></li>');
                //Create the divs and p tags 
                $("#dice_value").append('<div class="val_div"> <p class="val1"></p> <p class="val2"></p> <p class="val3"></p></div>');
            });
            //change information
            $("#info-txt").text("Välj en spelare!");
        }
        // On klick on a user make klicked user your own player.
        $("#my-list").on('click', '.list-a', function(){
            var currentPlayer = this.text;

            $("#info-txt").text("Tryck på spela knappen för att börja spelet!");
            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({height: '300px', opacity: '1'});
            $("#currentPlayer-h3").text(currentPlayer);

        });
        // On klick of the play button
        $("#startGame-button").click(function (){

            $("#dice_value").animate({ opacity: '1'});
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val1', function(){
                text = v1;
            });
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val2', function(){
                text = v2;
            });
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val3', function(){
                text = v3;
            });
            Game.roll_dice();
        });


    }

    return {
        init: init,
    }

})();
$(document).ready(function(){
    EventHandlers.init();
});
```

The problem I have is that the 3 dice values is not showing up, i guess it is not binding to this beacuse it is dynamicly added.

```
 $("#dice_value").append('<div class="val_div"> <p class="val1"></p> <p class="val2"></p> <p class="val3"></p></div>');
```

This is the code for what should happen when the start button is pressed and where i try to bind the dice values in the p tags:

```
// On klick of the play button
        $("#startGame-button").click(function (){

            $("#dice_value").animate({ opacity: '1'});
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val1', function(){
                text = v1;
            });
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val2', function(){
                text = v2;
            });
            $("#dice_value").ready('.val3', function(){
                text = v3;
            });
            Game.roll_dice();
        });
```

This is the html code:

```
<div id="top-div">
        <h1 id="title">The game</h1>
        <p id="info-txt"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="currentPlayer-div">
        <h1 id=playerHeader>Din spelare</h1>
        <h3 id="currentPlayer-h3"></h3>
        <button id="startGame-button">Spela</button>
    </div>
    <div id="main_gameDiv">
        <div id="dice_value"></div>
        <ul id="my-list"></ul>
    </div>
```

I hope that describes enough what I need help with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo, you're trying to use a jQuery object in a pure javascript way:

```js
function roll_dice(){
  var value1 = $(".val1");
  var value2 = $(".val2");
  var value3 = $(".val3");
  var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var v3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var dice_total = v1 + v2 + v3;
  
  // value1, value2 & value3 are jQuery objects, not javascript DOM elements
  //value1.text = v1;
  //value2.text = v2;
  //value3.text = v3;
  value1.html(v1);
  value2.html(v2);
  value3.html(v3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The values shows up but every player gets the same value of the three rolls...

Comment: Are you literally running this on two different browsers, or two different computers, or are you sort of simulating the game experience on a single interface?  Either way, this sounds like a separate question.

Comment: oh im sorry, just taught it was worth to ask if you maybe knew a simple way to solve it. Im just simulating the game on a single interface

Comment: I tried to do a "foreach user in the list run it" kind of way but then no numbers at all showed up. Now it takes the same random numbers for every user

Comment: it's probably an error in the way you're trying to simulate it, the fact that you tried it one way and it didn't show anything supports that idea.  If you have the server-side code complete, try running it on two different browsers, if you don't, then I suggest you write up a new question that includes your simulation code. You can tag me here with a link to your new question and I can try to look at it, but someone else may get to it before I have a chance.